# Adobe Flex :File Reference Error 1061

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, filereference

I want to save XML File using Flex 4 SDK

```
var fr:FileReference=new FileReference();
fr.save( newXmlRow, 'D:/Sample.xml' );
```

Error Shows :

```
1061 "Call to possibly Undefined method save through a reference with static type flash.net:FileReference"
```

Comment: What is target Flash Player version in your project settings?

Comment: Im Using Adobe Flash Player 10 .

Comment: Another question: is this error compile time or runtime?

Comment: So go to the project properties `> Flex Compiler > Adobe Flash Player Options` and please write what version is pointed there.

Comment: The `FileReference.save()` method is available in those the Flash Player 10 and AIR 1.5 runtime versions. If you're really using the Flex 4 SDK, those versions should be targeted by default. Are you sure you're using the Flex 4 SDK? The default minimum Flash Player version specified in Flex 3 is 9 and not 10.

Comment: @ Constantiner :I selected "Use Minimum Versionrequireed by the Flex SDK"

Comment: @Matt:Currently i developed application in Web ..not in AIR

Comment: @Constantiner:Whether i have to change the Flash Player 10.0.0 in Adobe Flash Player options

Comment: I changed adobe player options to 10.0.0 , ITs doesn,t shows error in compile time ,,But in run time it shows Error: Error #2087: The FileReference.download() file name contains prohibited characters.

Comment: @Constantiner & @Matt : Thanks .I got It Using of Adobe Flash Builder 10.0.0

Comment: @Kumar In regards to `Error #2087` the second parameter of `FileReference.save()` should be file name, not file path. Use `Sample.xml`.

Answer (score 3):

Hi Please change according to this, I am sure that you will definitely come out from this situation.

Right Click on the Project -> click on the properties -> Go to FLEX Compiler -> Change Required FLASH Player version to 10.0.0

[image]

After completing this click on the apply button and have fun...

Have a nice day...

Comment: how do I make this change if I'm using mxmlc.exe on the command line?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use background process for upload file.
Like create functon/webservice for upload file in c#.net.
You can not direct save file in flex.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I don't think the asker is talking about saving an upload to a server. The question is asking why saving a file in Flex, which is client-side, isn't working.

Comment: Im Using Adobe Falsh Player 10 .